# What is the proper way to select the time-bandwidth product when doing multi-taper spectral estimation?

Tags: fft, frequency-spectrum, estimation

Frequently programs for calculating the spectrum of a signal using the multi-taper method require the user to specify the time-bandwidth product.

What considerations must be made when selecting the time-bandwidth product? 
Would would be the effect on the resulting spectrum if the selected time-bandwidth product is too large or too small?

Comment: I think the idea is to go through several time-bandwidth products, not just a single one. Is there a paper you're using for reference?

Comment: @Phonon, no... I've been trying to hunt one down. The way I understand it is that the time-bandwidth product dictates the number of tapers that can be used to accurately estimate the PSD, however, if too many tapers are used the PSD becomes over smoothed and inaccurate.